# NSOpenPanel setAllowedFileTypes

Tags: objective-c, nsopenpanel

I have a NSOpenPanel. But I want to make it PDF-files selectable only. I'm looking for something like that:

```
// NOT WORKING 
NSOpenPanel *panel;

panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[panel setFloatingPanel:YES];
[panel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
[panel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
[panel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"pdf"]];
int i = [panel runModalForTypes:nil];
if(i == NSOKButton){
    return [panel filenames];
}
```

I hope someboby has a solution.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A couple things I noticed.. change `setCanChooseDirectories`to NO. When enabled this indicates that folders are valid input. This is most likely not the functionality you want. You might also want to change your allowed file types to `[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"pdf", @"PDF", nil]` for case sensitive systems. `runModalForTypes` should be the array of file types. Change your code to look like this:

```
// WORKING :)
NSOpenPanel *panel;
NSArray* fileTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"pdf", @"PDF", nil];
panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[panel setFloatingPanel:YES];
[panel setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
[panel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
[panel setAllowedFileTypes:fileTypes];
int i = [panel runModal];
if(i == NSOKButton){
    return [panel URLs];
}
```

Swift 4.2:

```
let fileTypes = ["jpg", "png", "jpeg"]
let panel = NSOpenPanel()
panel.canChooseFiles = true
panel.canChooseDirectories = false
panel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
panel.allowedFileTypes = fileTypes
panel.beginSheetModal(for: window) { (result) in
    if result.rawValue == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK.rawValue {
         // Do something with the result.
         let selectedFolder = panel.urls[0]
         print(selectedFolder)
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this leak fileTypes?

Comment: @MKatz thank you for the catch. Without ARC alloc must be followed by release. I will change it to arrayWithObjects:

Comment: This doesn't work although no errors are generated. The file selection window opens but all file types are displayed and can be selected normally....using Swift 5 on MacOS Mojave 10.14.5 XCode 11 Beta

Comment: `panel.allowedFileTypes = [NSImage imageTypes];` (obj-c syntax) to get all image types supported by `NSImage`.

Answer (score 2):

You are very close to the answer.

First, get rid of `[panel setCanChooseDirectories:YES]` so that it won't allow directories as a result.

Then, either change`[panel runModalForTypes:nil]` to `[panel runModal]` or get rid of the call to `[panel setAllowedFileTypes:]` and pass the array to `[panel runModalForTypes:]` instead.